# Why does my media query work in codepen but not vs code?

Tags: html, css

I tried adding a media query to my vs code project and just to check if it is working I like to do a small check of changing the background color. For some reason it will not work in vs code, Whenever I click inspect on the static page and lower the width the background color does not change.

I then went into code pen and tried it out there with the same code and it works fine there. What could it be? Is it a vs problem or something I'm doing wrong in the code?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
}

@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width”>
```

Comment: The use of the wrong kind of quotation marks is likely to break it on mobile. Maybe the preview tool you are using doesn't support media queries.

Comment: Hey so i kept refreshing added a p tag just to test out further i also changed the quotation marks and it everything started working. I'm new to stack overflow so i dont know how to give you credit for this answer.

Comment: If the problem was just that typo, you might as well delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Quentin noted and I have confirmed, the quotation marks are messing with the meta tag. It should look like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

But when pasting your code, VS code auto corrects to this (improper):

```
<meta name="”viewport”" content="”width" ="device-width”" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey so yea i did fix it and now everything works. I'm fairly new to coding, does the meta tag have that much of an impact on media queries where if the meta tag isn't good the media query wont work?.

Comment: @Nas — Only on mobile devices which would otherwise assume the website was designed without small screens in mind and scale it to a zoomed out desktop view.

Comment: Yes, if there is no viewport meta tag, there is a chance that your media queries will not work. I have not dug too deep into the actual logic behind the viewport meta tag, but I know that you need it. Side Note: when starting an Html file in vs, type '!' and select the first emmet abbreviation, it will save you a lot of time with boilerplate HTML. for more emmet shortcuts see: https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/